# Generate all combinations of multiple object types

Tags: php, math, combinations

I have two classes : `A.php` and `B.php`

I want to generate all combinations of **one** A object and **two** B objects.

For example, let's say I have these objects :

```
A1
A2

B1
B2 
B3
```

Here's the combinations that I would like to generate :

```
A1 B1 B2
A1 B1 B3
A1 B2 B3

A2 B1 B2
A2 B1 B3
A2 B2 B3
```

I'm using the `Math_Combinatorics` package, found here : https://github.com/pear/Math_Combinatorics

I can use it to generate all the combinations of the same types of objects :

```
$Math = new Math_Combinatorics;
$objectsB = [$objectB1, $objectB2, $objectB3];
$combinations = $Math->combinations($objectsB, 2); 

// Which results in ...
$object1, $object2
$object1, $object3
$object2, $object3
```

However, I don't know how to achieve this when I want to generate combinations for different objects of different types, in varying amounts.

In this case it's **one** of A and **two** of B, but ideally this would work for any amount of each types.

Comment: have you tried with diff objects?

Comment: in any case, you can receive all combinations of B objects and in usual loop add A objects in each array

Comment: I haven't tried different objects with the Math_Combinatorics library, I'm not sure how that would work. The first argument the `combinations()` method accepts is an array of your objects, the second argument is the set size. The set size is different for both.

Comment: Doing a nested loop does work @splash58, but it's terribly slow when working with large sets and I'd like to find a better, more efficient way to do it.

Comment: @Drown, I don't think there is a more efficient way than 3 nested loops to do what you ask, maybe except for calling the code that does those loops in C rather than PHP. If your sets are large, resulting combinations set will be huge. It should be `size(A) * size(B) * (size(B) - 1)` and you can't avoid creating all those objects.

Comment: If you wanted to do this in a functional way, you'd combine the pairs of Bs you have with the A choices using a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). The library you reference doesn't seem to implement that. Might be a suitable addition, though.